# Write to s3 from Hive fails

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, cloudera

I am trying to setup a Hadoop Cluster to write Hive tables to s3.

- Setup the s3 connector
- Create external tables on s3 is working fine
- [Updated the keys in core-site.xml](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-12-x/topics/cm_s3_clients.html)
- [Updated the encryption to AES256](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/9942)
- Local on HDFS is working fine.

I am getting the following error from s3: (This is a single line error broken up for read-ability)

```
FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: 
Unable to determine if s3a://<MyBucket>/hive/warehouse/<My>.db/<MyTable> is encrypted: 
java.io.InterruptedIOException: doesBucketExist on <MyBucket>: 
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: 
No AWS Credentials provided by 
  BasicAWSCredentialsProvider
  EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider 
  SharedInstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : 
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException:
Unable to load credentials from service endpoint
```

[A Similar Issue is described here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1398)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a Good Workout and a good rest is the solution:

[This link talks about the fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider](https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hadoop/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html)

```
If unspecified, then the default list of credential provider classes,
queried in sequence, is:
1. org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.BasicAWSCredentialsProvider: supports
    static configuration of AWS access key ID and secret access key.
    See also fs.s3a.access.key and fs.s3a.secret.key.
```

The issue was I had specified the keys in the **hadoop** conf `/etc/hadoop/conf` and not the **hive** conf `/etc/hive/conf`. Moving over the `fs.s3a.access.key` and `fs.s3a.secret.key` resolved the issue.

Comment: Interesting. I'd have expected Hive to pick up the core-site.xml settings. I've just learned something about hive that I didn't know.